# Decoding payload with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, payload, decoder

i need some support in parsing a payload with javascript. Below you see the json body. I need to return only the valuetype "occupants".

```js
{"id":"8684bc99-5a69-4b7a-92c2-69faa91b668b","type":"airthings-webhook-cloudevent-occupancy-ventilation-sample-feed","source":"https://dashboard.airthings.com/integrations/webhooks/2c823594-3c4b-4352-9929-8486a5f8a985","dataContentType":"application/json","labels":{},"data":[{"measurementSystem":"METRIC","serialNumber":"2930118961","recorded":"2022-05-04T08:55:00","occupants":4.0,"ventilationAmount":171.0,"ventilationState":true,"ratings":{},"sensorUnits":{"occupants":"occ","ventilationAmount":"m3h","relativeVentilationRate":"ach"}}],"time":"2022-05-04T08:58:20.322709","specVersion":"0.2"}
```

I made it to return the "data" array with the following decoder. Now i need the object "occupants" within data. Can someone tell me what I need to adjust in the following code?

```js
function Decoder(request) {

    // Parse JSON into Object
    var payload = JSON.parse(request.body);
    
    // Load Data from JSON
    var data = payload.data;
    var Occupancy = data.occupants;
    //var humidity = data.hum;
    //var battery = data.bat;
    
    // Forward Data into Device using Serial
    return data;
  
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  It seems perhaps you have not noted that `data` is not an object but an _array_ of objects.  So to get the `occupants` property value you first need to get the item at the proper index: `data[0].occupants` will give you `4`.

Comment: `payload.data` is an array that could contain more than one object, with more than one `occupants` property.  Do you just want the first?  `data[0].occupants` - Do you want all of them in an array?  `data.map(d => d.occupants)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me solving my problem.